# Hibernate performing too many queries

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I believe that I'm misunderstanding how subselect and eager works; my goal is to improve performance as I encounter the N+1 problem

**Edit** I'm wondering whether it would be quicker for me to just use the create SQL query method and create the objects myself although I was hoping hibernate would be on par with performance. I can pull back all of the data required, in the example below, in a single query so why on earth is hibernate doing a separate query for each?

I've created the following test case to highlight my issue, please excuse the crudity of this model..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Area")
public class Area implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "areaId" )
    @GenericGenerator(name = "areaId", strategy = "uuid2")
    public String areaId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "area", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    public Set<EmployeeArea> employeeAreas = new HashSet<EmployeeArea>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "employeeId" )
    @GenericGenerator(name = "employeeId", strategy = "uuid2")
    public String employeeId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    public Set<EmployeeArea> employeeAreas = new HashSet<EmployeeArea>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EmployeeArea")
public class EmployeeArea implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "employeeAreaId" )
    @GenericGenerator(name = "employeeAreaId", strategy = "uuid2")
    public String employeeAreaId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    public Employee employee;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    public Area area;
}
```

I have then populated with some sample test data: -

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
Area area = new Area();

EmployeeArea employeeArea = new EmployeeArea();
employeeArea.area = area;
employeeArea.employee = employee;

session.save(employee);
session.save(area);
session.save(employeeArea);
```

This can be run a few times to provide some data.

I then perform the following: -

```
session.createQuery("FROM Employee e INNER JOIN e.employeeAreas ea INNER JOIN ea.area").list();
```

*The reason I do the JOIN is so that I can perform specialist searches. I was looking at criteria but it seemed that it didn't allow me to do all that I could with WHERE*

I would expect that it would be doing at most 3 queries and 2 sub queries.

1. SELECT * FROM Employee INNER JOIN EmployeeArea ON condition INNER JOIN Area ON condition
2. SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE employeeId IN (subquery 1)
3. SELECT * FROM Area WHERE areaId IN (subquery 2)

In fact, for 6 inputs of the test data aforementioned, I seem to be getting 6 selects for an employee, 6 selects for an area, something that looks like my assumed query for '1.' and then two larger queries that seem just plain wrong: -

> ```
> select
>     employeear0_.employee_employeeId as employee2_3_2_,
>     employeear0_.employeeAreaId as employee1_4_2_,
>     employeear0_.employee_employeeId as employee2_4_2_,
>     employeear0_.area_areaId as area3_4_2_,
>     employeear0_.employeeAreaId as employee1_4_1_,
>     employeear0_.employee_employeeId as employee2_4_1_,
>     employeear0_.area_areaId as area3_4_1_,
>     area1_.areaId as areaId1_0_0_ 
> from
>     EmployeeArea employeear0_ 
> inner join
>     Area area1_ 
>         on employeear0_.area_areaId=area1_.areaId 
> where
>     employeear0_.employee_employeeId in (
>         select
>             employee1_.employeeId 
>         from
>             EmployeeArea employeear0_ 
>         inner join
>             Employee employee1_ 
>                 on employeear0_.employee_employeeId=employee1_.employeeId 
>         where
>             employeear0_.area_areaId in (
>                 select
>                     area2_.areaId 
>                 from
>                     Employee employee0_ 
>                 inner join
>                     EmployeeArea employeear1_ 
>                         on employee0_.employeeId=employeear1_.employee_employeeId 
>                 inner join
>                     Area area2_ 
>                         on employeear1_.area_areaId=area2_.areaId
>                 )
>             )
> ```

then a very similar one for area.

My goal is to be able to use each employee object in the returned list to identify the areas worked in. There would be more fields in each entity however this test case has been simplified.

Comment: Have you tried FetchMode.JOIN?

Comment: Replacing with JOIN results in a StackOverflowError (using the code above)

Comment: did u try fetch join instead of inner join? Employee e fetch join e.employeeAreas

Comment: Why do you use the following HQL "FROM Employee e INNER JOIN e.employeeAreas ea INNER JOIN ea.area". You can just retrieve "FROM Employee" the rest will be fetched automatically, because of EAGER FetchType.

Comment: Fetch join is use to override LAZY loading with EAGER. It's not the case here.

Comment: @Squeezer, when I need to include conditions such as specific areas, I was under the impression I would need to join the table

Comment: I think Hibernate will create joins automatically.

Comment: Why don't you use LAZY initialization? It is common to use LAZY for collections.

Comment: @Sqeezer: Inner joins can filter from `Employee`.

Comment: I am aware of LAZY but it's not what I would like to do in this circumstance

Comment: @chrisw69 I have tried to write your model on a paper. And yes, there is a loop here if we use JOIN strategy. Can you try to link Area to EmployeeArea lazily, while Employee eagerly loads EmployeeAreas?

Comment: I will create a test case for this

Comment: Also, I believe, your model should be a bit different. Something like Employee *->1 EmployeeArea *->1 Area

Comment: hm, I am not sure I agree, I would have thought that since an employee can work in many areas and an area can have many employees, there is a  need for a join table to ensure that referential integrity is not violated which is why there is a one to many on each side but only a one to many from the join table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem; it was an issue with my join table. See the following: -

```
@Id
@ManyToOne
public Employee employee;

@Id
@ManyToOne
public Area area;
```

I had used @Id which was resulting in the StackOverflowError exception that was being thrown. Using the following query, with a OneToMany fetch of EAGER and @Fetch JOIN on Employee and a OneToMany fetch of LAZY and @Fetch SELECT on Area, I can then perform the following query: -

```
List<Employee> employees = session.createQuery("FROM Employee e INNER JOIN FETCH e.employeeAreas ea INNER JOIN FETCH ea.area").list();
```

Whilst being able to use WHERE on the one of the join table columns.

Answer (score 3):

Use `JOIN` strategy and link `Area` to `EmployeeArea` lazily, while `Employee` eagerly loads `EmployeeAreas`. When `Employee` loads `EmployeeArea`, hibernate session is populated with `EmployeeArea` objects. Then if you navigate through `Employee.EmployeeArea.Area.EmloyeeArea` nothing will be get from a database, because we already have `EmployeeArea` in the session cache.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, this results in a StackOverflowError using the specified test case.

Comment: INNER JOIN e.employeeAreas ea INNER JOIN ea.area. This causes the overflow. Take a look. First we join to employeeAreas, then we join it to Area, which also has many employeeAreas.

Comment: Yes, as your answer stipulates, I removed JOINs, unfortunately this results in the same using the test case above.

Comment: I have changed the fetch type for employeeArea/area to lazy and changed both fetches to JOIN however there is still a stack overflow exception. I'm not sure this is the solution I'm after. If I remove all of the fetch annotations; I'm getting more sensible queries but I'm just concerned that it's doing N selects instead of using a subselect..

Comment: Solved the problem, it was bad use of @Id on the Join Table, +1 for the lazy load of area.